# Override beats Overload? Why does that make sense at all?

Tags: java, oop, types, overloading

**Why should a super method hand out it's *this* reference as super type instead of own type?**

I don't understand the practicality of this behavior. I learned to code against Types/Interfaces and not against classes, but considering this kind of behavior I'm confused about everything I thought OOP was standing for. This breaks possibility of clean code and forces me to fill it with verbose control flow like heavy use of the *instanceof* operator. *Why does that kind of behavior make even sense?*

**Abstract:**
Consider this code:

```
abstract class A {
    public void visit(Target t) {
         t.method(this);
    }
}
```

If `Target` overloads `method()` with A and different child classes of A in it's signature and these children don't override `visit(Target t)` themselves then overloaded `method(A a)` will be choosen by compiler always.

**Working example:**
http://pastebin.com/EGNpY7pF

**Code Snip**

```
public class Target {

public static abstract class A {
    void visit(Target t) {
        t.method(this);
    }
}

public static class B extends A {}
public static class C extends A {
    @Override
    void visit(Target t) {
        t.method(this);
    }
}

void method(A a) { System.out.println("A");}
void method(B b) { System.out.println("B");}
void method(C c) { System.out.println("C");}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Target t = new Target();
    A ab = new B();
    B b = new B();
    A ac = new C();
    C c = new C();

    ab.visit(t);
    b.visit(t);
    ac.visit(t);
    c.visit(t);

}
```

}

**Output**
A A C C
Which is really akward since `ac` is referenced to as `A`-Type but still `C`'s overriden `visit()` method is called.

Comment: Can you post a more complete code snippet into your question, as your description is somewhat hard to follow.

Comment: Having that method in `A` doesn't mean that implementation gets literally copied into each of its subclasses.  There's only one copy of `A.visit` anywhere, and that one copy refers specifically to the overload `t.method(A)`.

Comment: here is your code with an output http://ideone.com/1s14qi

Comment: I see what you're saying, Louis Wasserman. Since in `A`'s visit it's decided at compile time which `method()` will be called if no subclass overrides `visit()` it's static and not dynamic. Weak.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. When a function is called on an instance of an object the child's method will be called, even if it is referenced as its parent's type; polymorphism.  If the child does not override the method then the parent class' implementation of the method will be called; inheritance from hierarchy.

If a class calls its own method prefixing it with super it will find the nearest implementation up the hierarchy which matches the signature.